# What motion estimation techniques that could estimate the motion of every pixel?

Tags: image-processing, motion-estimation

I'm trying to estimate a motion from a video, however based on my finding, those methods usually meant for large motion and sparse in nature.

Optical flow: Sparse and fail to detect sub-pixel motion

[Phase-based](http://people.csail.mit.edu/mrub/VisualMic/): Only applicable to global shutter camera for accurate displacement

Welcome any suggestion/discussion you guys have in mind that would allow me to determine sub-pixel motion for **every pixel** that applicable to rolling shutter camera! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm afraid that what you're asking for doesn't compute.  You want the "sub-pixel motion for every pixel" -- does this mean you have as many objects as pixels, or that you have a few super-small objects, or what?  You need to give more information.  As to correcting for rolling shutter -- I think you'll need to estimate the object's speed and position, and then correct for the rolling shutter.  This may be an iterative process, and it's certainly going to difficult as the object's speed approaches the speed of the shutter (and impossible when it reaches it).

Comment: Traditional Lukas-Kanade optical flow is dense and estimates sub-pixel displacements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Farneback to estimate dense flow.  In OpenCV, the function call is calcOpticalFlowFarneback().

Please note that the initial flow is important and you can use one of OPTFLOW_FARNEBACK_GAUSSIAN or OPTFLOW_USE_INITIAL_FLOW.

It depends on the depth of the pre calculation to estimate the segmentation before calculating the frame to frame flow.